# Timestamp field in cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am having a hard time using ts field in cosmos/document db with c#. Is it just better to create another date time field and use that instead of ts? How to decide when to use ts vs a custom date time field?

Comment: _ts is an internal property. You should not take a dependency on it. Recommend creating one or more date/time properties (i.e. createDate, lastModified, etc.) in ISO 8601 and using that instead. More date info can be found here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/working-with-dates

Comment: I am just using it for read purpose. Is it not recommended to even use it for read purpose? Also are you from the azure cosmos db team?

Comment: @user911 - `_ts` will change, as the contents of your document change. There's nothing you can rely on, aside from the time  a document was created or edited. So yes, you can read `_ts`, but what will that value mean to you? If you need something like a creation date, then you need to store your own date, as Mark already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

`_ts` represents a Unix Epoch and marks the time of the document's last modification. When a document is created, it has the creation time, but if later on the document is updated, then `_ts` is updated with that time.

Effectively it means the last modified time of the document.

It depends on your use case if you can use it or you need a custom date field. For example, if your intent it to track when a document was created, then you **can't** use it, as the value will change if the document is modified. If your intent is to track the last modified time, it **can** work (depends on the precision you need and if a Unix Epoch fills that requirement, otherwise you would need your own custom field).

Here is the official reference of system properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/account-databases-containers-items#properties-of-an-item